# Почему не работает условие в ModX

Tags: modx

Добрый день! У меня к вам вопрос, использую modx для проектирования интернет-магазина, используются компоненты minishop. Делаю вызов мини-корзины со своим чанком:

```
[[!msMiniCart? &tpl=`tpl.msMiniCart-surpriz`]]
```

В шаблоне tpl.msMiniCart-surpriz прописываю следующее условие:

```
<div id="msMiniCart"><strong class="ms2_total_count">[[+total_count]]</strong> [[[[+total_count]]:is=`0`:then=`<p>ничего нет</p>`:else=`<p>есть что-то в корзине...</p>`]]</div>
```

И в результате общее количество товаров в корзине выводит, а условие не срабатывает, то есть нету надписи "ничего нет" или "есть что-то в корзине...". В чем может быть причина? Подскажите?

Answer (score 2):

Если кому поможет это, то правильный ответ таков:

```
<div id="msMiniCart"><strong class="ms2_total_count">[[+total_count]]</strong> [[+total_count:is=`0`:then=`<p>ничего нет</p>`:else=`<p>есть что-то в корзине...</p>`]]</div>
```

И тогда все работает.